# Dictionary in GraphQL resolver of NestJS

Tags: typescript, graphql, nestjs

In my NestJS project I'm creating a GraphQL endpoint for a service that returns a dictonary object:

```
{
 [key: number]: MyDataDto
}
```

In my `.interfaces.ts` file I would like to have something like:

```
interface ArrayAsObject<T> {
  [key: number]: T
}

@ObjectType()
export class MyDataDtoAsDictionary implements ArrayAsObject<MyDataDto> {
  @Field(() => MyDataDto)
  [key: number]: MyDataDto
}
```

But it gives me an error on the line with `@Field`

> Decorators are not valid here. (ts1206)

If I remove the `@Field` decorator it throws:

> Type MyDataDtoAsDictionary must define one or more fields.

What is the right way to decorate that kind of object for GraphQL resolver?

Comment: Did you ever find the answer or did you choose another approach?

Comment: @TheHiggsBroson No, I haven't find any proper solution, so I had to create another service that would return an array of `MyDataDto` and handle it a bit differently in frontend app.

Comment: Has anyone had the solution, graphql seems not to encourage it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41559109/4984888

Answer (score 0):

You can use **graphql-type-json** as response type of a Query in your Resolver.

First of all, you need to install graphql-type-json: https://www.npmjs.com/package/graphql-type-json

```
npm i graphql-type-json
```

With this, you can return a Dictionary with a Query like this:

```
export class EquipmentResolver { 
  private data: { [key: number]: MyDataDto } = {};

  @Query(() => graphqlTypeJson)
  async queryData() {
    return this.data;
  }
}
```

In a frontend project you can pipe this very easily with **RxJS** back to a Dictionary:

```
export class DataComponent {
  private data: { [key: number]: MyDataDto } = {};

  private loadData() {
    this.graphqlService
    .queryData()
    .pipe(
      map((response: { [key: number]: MyDataDto) => {
        this.data = response;
      })
    )
    .subscribe();
  }
}
```

You can use the same construct in your **ObjectType**:

```
@ObjectType()
export class MyDataDtoAsDictionary implements 
  ArrayAsObject<MyDataDto> {

  @Field(() => graphqlTypeJson, { nullable: true })
  data: { [key: number]: MyDataDto }
}
```